# Enum in Rails unit tests

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I am working on testing some legacy code. One of the tables has an `enum` column. (I know, don't hate. I didn't write it).

Everything works fine until a try to run a unit test. Suddenly the database schema is saving the `enum` column as a `varchar(0)`. The obviously doesn't let me set any value.

Here's my big question. How can I add a hook to the `rake test:units` to adjust the column type? It doesn't matter if its an `enum` or just a `varchar(100)`.

Thanks!

Comment: what does [Your Model Name].columns_hash[Your Enum Column Name].type return is it varchar(0)?

Comment: That command returns `string` but the database shows it is stored as `varchar(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this problem turned out to have an easier solution than I expected. In the `environment.rb` file there is a section:

```
# Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the test database.
# This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
# like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
# config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Uncommenting the last line means two things. First, the schema is exported in SQL instead of Ruby. Second, database specific datatypes are preserved.

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Comment: Wow much simpler glad you figured it out.

Comment: I just upvoted another one of your questions. I don't want to through off the order of the answers here, but at least you got some rep from it.

Comment: As with all things in life the solution is more important than the credit. Your answer is correct mine is a hack and so it goes.

Comment: Still, you put in the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am not suggesting this as a solution to all problems but in this case you could hack in your own rake task to change the column type to a string as so:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Change column type"
    task :test_setup do
      Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].invoke
      Rails.env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
      ActiveRecord::Migration.change_table :YOUR_TABLE_NAME do |t|
        t.change :YOUR_ENUM_COLUMN_NAME, :string, :limit => 100
      end
    end
end
```

This file would be placed in lib/tasks as `whatever_you_want_to_call_it.rake.`
Then instead of `rake db:test:prepare` you would run `rake db:test_setup` which will run `rake db:test:prepare` and then alter the enum column to a `varchar(100)` which I believe will satisfy your needs here. Please correct me if I am wrong.

You should also be able to plug in your call to test:units here too with `Rake::Task['test:units'].invoke` although I have not tested this.

Again hacking things like this is not something I would generally recommend since you are really changing the data type and how it is handled by the database but since this is what you requested I thought I would try and help.

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually found a better way to do it this morning. Thanks for the effort though.